# Can't get id from previous page Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I have a button to see detail about user using button in each row datatable, the button will call a route detail.show and open link with user_id with it (ex:http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/7),
here is the button code

```
->addColumn('action', function ($post) {
                    $link = "route('detail.show',$post->user_id)";
                    $btn = ' <a href="' . route("detail.show", $post->user_id) . '"data-original-title="Detail" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-sm detailProduct"><span class="fas fa-eye"></span></a>';

                    return $btn;
                })
```

the problem is I cant get any data from it, is there something wrong?
here is my route

```
Route::resource('detail', DetailController::class);
```

Here is my controller

```
 public function show($user_id)
    {
        $post = Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->latest()->get();

        return view('detail', compact('post'));
    }
```

and here is my view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="float-left">
            <h2> Show Post</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>User ID:</strong>
            {{ $post->user_id }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            {{ $post->name }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I cant show anything using code as shown above. Is there something wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: where is the data table here?? it's not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this can often be solved by structuring your logic to be cleaner, more straightforward and use constructs of the framework as intended (documented).

In this case I would treat a user as resource and not the "detail".

**I would rather create a specific route for showing the specific details of the user or just use [partial resource routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes).**

Anyway, if you would like to keep your current build:

If I remember correctly, parameter passed to the show function in the controller should match the parameter name in your route.

When you generate routes with
Route::resource('detail', DetailController::class);
it creates something like
/details/{detail}
for the show method.
As described in [this part of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller).

Try replacing

```
$user_id
```

with

```
$detail
```

in your show method.